# MuPDF Library not working on X86 architectures

Tags: android, x86, mupdf

This question was already asked by someone, But there i can't find any clues about the issue. I am using MuPDF library to open and preview the .pdf files in our Android application. It's working fine other than few X86 architecture devices. I got the following issue

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.demo-1/lib/x86/libmupdf.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40
   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:371)
   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
   at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.(MuPDFCore.java:19)
   at com.demo.openwith.OpenwithFragment.openFile(OpenwithFragment.java:789)
   at com.demo.openwith.OpenwithFragment.openPDF(OpenwithFragment.java:671)
   at com.demo.openwith.OpenwithFragment.onCreateView(OpenwithFragment.java:346)
   at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
   at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
   at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6047)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

previously i have used the old library(.so) of the MuPDF. Now i have updated the recent library, even i am getting the same issue. Can anyone help me to find the reason and fix the issue.

Comment: DO you have the x86 version of the .so?  The x86-64?  Are you using the appropriate one?

Comment: Are you using an x86-64 JVM or a 32-bit JVM?

Answer (score 1):

create ***libs*** folder in app/src/main
then create folder **x86** download this file and insert it

https://github.com/minaairsupport/MuPDF_Android_Studio/blob/master/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86/libmupdf_java.so